# How a P-Frame is constructed in H.264 codec when processing a raw video

Tags: video, encoding, video-streaming, h.264, video-processing

I am trying to understand the working of video codec in general, one of them being `H.264`.

I have gone through some articles on the web about the working of `H.264` and I hope to have got some understanding of the same.

While reading about the same I got to know about the different types of frames such as `I-Frame`, `P-Frame` and `B-Frame` which are being used when streaming a video encoded using `H.264`.

What I could not understand is given a raw video which obviously have data present in it in terms of frame, literature on the web says that `I-Frame` is the original frame as it is where as `P-Frame` is predicted from the previous `I-Frame` or `P-Frame`, here how could a `P-Frame` is predicted from another `P-Frame` when the same doesn't exist yet.

Also what confuses me is the prediction of `P-Frame`.

Kindly help to understand the same or refer a literature which is explaining the same.

Comment: From what I know is that when ever an video encoding is started the first frame of the encoded video is always `I-Frame`.

Comment: `P-frame` means that only some pixels still exist (usually the moving/changed ones) and the rest of picture is predicted (or copied) based on whats already known from previous frame. See top part of this **[image](http://www.pilarsomohano.com/portals/0/Images/MPEG_basics_612.jpg)**. Remember video frames moves forward in time so you can always check a previous frame's image (which itself looks like a key frame when all parts are decoded and pieced together)

Comment: Also in H.264 there a `motion vectors` to direct the flow of pixels etc. So technically you can call it "predicting" where the pixels should be placed in this image.

Comment: @VC.One you should promote your comments to an answer. This really a terminology problem because nothing is "predicted", like in "predicted by an oracle". Rather, subsequent P-frames are constructed from the available information represented by I-frame and P-frames using motion vectors and transform coefficients. With B frames is gets more complicated.

Comment: @VC.One Your comment really clarifies one thing i.e `P-Frame` is constructed from the previous `I-Frame` and hence in a video transmission the first frame to be transferred has to be an `I-Frame`. However as said of `B-Frames` it uses previous and future frames , I am not sure how a system can look at a future frame. It would be helpful if someone can help on that.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza you should also check this **[article](https://codesequoia.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/find-the-mpeg-output-order-from-decoding-order/)** and maybe this PDF of a **[H.264 Decoder Manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprab88/sprab88.pdf)** might help you understand the frame-types relation...

Comment: @KrishnaOza : h.264 is used e.g. in Video post-processing. So you can "look into the future" if you already have the whole clip. When streaming/live broadcasting the clip, this of course means, that you have an offset. But the offset is just one frame.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering your last comment about B-frames. The video encoder has a buffer which keeps a certain amount of frames.

Let's consider an example where your first 4 frames are to be encoded with following structure: IBBP.

The first frame is encoded as an I-frame (intra). Frame 2 and 3 are B frames and cannot be encoded right away because they are waiting for the "future" frame P. So they are put in the buffer. When frame 4 arrives at the encoder, it is inter-encoded (unidirectional), with the first frame (I-frame) as a reference. Now that the P-frame has been encoded, the frames 2 and 3 which are bidirectional, and thus need references in the past and in the future, can be encoded (inter, bidirectional).

So the encoding order is: I P B B. Which is not the same order as the display order.

As you can see, B-frames introduce delays in the encoding process, and are thus generally not used in low-delay applications such as videoconferencing.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the difference between **decoding order** and **display order**. This is why MPEG decoders deal with **PTS** (Presentation TimeStamp) for display and there is **DTS** (Decoder TimeStamp) which tell what time that frame should be decoded and held  in buffer or displayed.. So the **P-frame** would have a sooner **DTS** than the **B-frames** but, for the end video viewer, the image at the frame/time slots of the **B-frames** will display first (at time-unit 2 and time-unit 3) before the **P-frame** at (time-unit 4).. Thus future prediction (or analysis) to show a "sooner" image.